# Erro ao compilar aplicação SPRING BOOT

Tags: java, postgresql, api, spring-boot, rest

Estou tentando compilar uma aplicação java e está dando esse erro:

```
 restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : 
  Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: 
   Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

meu pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cartorios</groupId>
    <artifactId>apirest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>apirest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
</dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Minha aplication:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.username=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Poste a stacktrace completa

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, acredito que você vai precisar criar no arquivo de propriedades o caminho do driver do banco que você vai usar, vi que você declarou o Postgres é o Mysql, então no arquivo application.properties você vai precisar colocar assim.
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver. espero que te ajude. :)

Comment: Deu certo :D muito obrigado!

Comment: Nao apenas agradeca, de upvote e selecione como a resposta correta. As pessoas dedicam o tempo delas aqui para terem reconhecimento da contribuicao delas futuramente.